# In rails selecting with radiobuttons shouldn't interfere with nested editing form of one of the select options

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, forms, radio-button

In a check out environment a customer can choose from a list of addresses to which his package should be delivered to. This is done with a radio button next to each delivery address.

*deliveries/_select_form.rb*

```ruby
<% if deliveries.any? %>

<%= form_for [:set_package_delivery, order], name: "select_address" do |f| %>

    <% deliveries.each do |delivery| %>
      <div id='delivery-ajax-<%= delivery.id %>'>
        <%= render delivery,
              card_title: "#{delivery.address_zip_code}, #{delivery.address_street_number}",
              form: deliveries.size > 1 ? f : false  %>
      </div>
    <% end %>

<% end %>

<% end %>
```

Because each address needs to be directly added to the order, I used an `:onclick` event to submit with a single click on a radio button.

*deliveries/_delivery*

```ruby
<div class='delivery'>
  <nav class='record-bar'>
    <% if controller.action_name == 'check_out' && form %>
      <div class='select-button'>
        <%= form.radio_button :package_delivery_id, delivery.id, :onclick => "this.closest('form').submit();" %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
    <div class='title'>
      <h4 class='address'><%= card_title %></h4>
    </div>
    <% if !(controller.action_name == 'confirm' ||
        controller.action_name == 'pay') &&
        policy(delivery).edit? %>
      <div class='actions'>
          <%= link_to [:edit, delivery.sender, delivery], remote: true do %>
            <i class='fa fa-pencil'></i>
          <% end %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
  </nav>

  <p>
    <%= delivery.address_street_name %>
    <%= delivery.address_street_number %><br>
    <%= delivery.address_zip_code %><br>
    <%= delivery.address_city %><br>
  </p>
</div>
```

Then the problem starts: as you can see in the `_delivery` partial above, there is a `remote: true` edit form (which makes it possible to still adjust the newly added address (`delivery`) that has not yet been used on anything send out).

When you click it the following form renders in the browser screen:

*deliveries/_form*

```ruby
<%= form_for [delivery.sender, delivery], remote: true do |ff| %>
<%= ff.hidden_field :sender_id, value: delivery.sender.id %>

<div class='delivery'>
<table>
  <tr>
    <div class="field">
      <th><%= ff.label :address_street_name %></th>
      <td><%= ff.text_field :address_street_name %></td>
    </div>
  </tr>

  # ...omitted rest of input fields
</table>

  <div class='button-center'>
    <%= ff.submit "Opslaan", class: 'button' %>
  </div>

</div>
<% end %>
```

Then the problem occurs: when submitting the edited delivery-address form i get the error:

## NoMethodError in OrdersController#set_package_delivery

**undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass**

```ruby
  def set_package_delivery
    @deliveries = @order.customer.deliveries
    >>@delivery = Delivery.find(params[:order][:package_delivery_id])
    @order.package_delivery = @delivery
    @order.save!
  end
```

Which is a little nonsensical, because I don't need the controller action:

**orders#set_package_delivery**

Which you would need when selecting the single delivery-address, but I need the following action to succeed, obviously:

**deliveries#update**

They do work separately from each other, but the nested edit form does not make this functional at the moment.

Comment: are you nesting forms ?, that's not possible. Try rendering your remote `deliveries/_form` partial outside of your main form.

Comment: Figured that one out today as well. This would mean I'd have to change my view specifically for this though (or code really a lot). Maybe once I'll move on to rails as an API and a JS framework on the front this can be solved more easily.